# Yii. Изменение формата логирования

Tags: yii, логирование

Всем привет!

Такой вопрос: логгер по-умолчанию пишет в application.log в формете date:type и бла-бла-бла.

Где, собственно,хранится порядок строки,которая попадает в файл с логом?

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил, сам нашел ответ:
класс **CLogRoute**, функция **formatLogMessage**.

Автопять!